# How can i find and Display latest inserted value/data in SQL server using Vb.net

Tags: android, sql-server, vb.net

I designed a android application to insert values into a SQL Server database.
Android application users will insert data every minute.

So I created vb.net windows application to view the data. How can I get the latest inserted value on sqlserver table to Vb.net without slowing the application down? If I use timer, Vb.net application will get slow due to to reading the data every second

Comment: Dou you mean [BackgroundWorker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You'll have to insert the current date/time in your record, then it's only a matter of ordering by that date.

Comment: @the_lotus .fine...Another dout to Display automatically in datagrid  after inserting from android app.........can i use timer to get data periodically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You execute for a scalar value - the value last inserted. Then you can insert new data.

To Insert:

```
Dim id As Integer
Dim sql As String = ""
Using con As SqlConnection(connStr)
  sql = "Select Top 1 [id column] From tableName Order By [id column] Desc"
  Using cmd As SqlCommand(sql, con)
     id = cmd.ExecuteScalar() + 1
     sql = "Insert ... statement with last id"
     'reinitialize the command object'
     cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
Using
```

Get records:

```
Dim sql As String = ""
Using con As SqlConnection(connStr)
  sql = "Select * From tableName"
  Using cmd As SqlCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
Using
```

Comment: Thanks @OneFineday..............But to Automatically display on my Datagrid can i use Timer control with that Sql query ?

Comment: You load the data to the `DataSource` with the second chuck of code. I don't know if you need  where clause in there, but that should be easy to add.